# Issues converting a list of times in Python?

Tags: python, list, time

I have a list of times in seconds which I would like to convert to human readable time, UTC. My times are in seconds since Jan 1, 1978, at 0 hours, 0 mins, and 0 seconds. So from my list, `times`, I have first substracted eight multiplied by the number of seconds in a year, as the `time` package uses UNIX epoch.

```
import time
times = times - (8*31556926)
for i in range(12191):
    times[i] = time.gmtime([times[i]])
```

which returns

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)
```

I have attempted to convert to a list of integers by two methods:

```
times[i] = time.gmtime(int([timelist[i]]))
```

which throws

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

and

```
timelist = [int(times) for times in times]
for i in range(12191):
    times[i] = time.gmtime([timelist[i]])
```

which throws

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)
```

I'm new to Python and haven't used the time package before - has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `times[i] = time.gmtime([times[i]])` you sould use `times[i] = time.gmtime(int(times[i]))` becuase `times[i]` returns a string which can be converted to interger using `int()` but you placed `times[i]` into another pair of `[]` wich makes it into a list with one item in it.

Comment: Thank you! Of course it was a silly bracket mistake. This worked.